# Security Concerns with Private Repos in GitHub

Tags: github

I have signed up my organization to a GitHub Teams free plan, and we are considering pushing our code to private repositories on GitHub. Our projects consist of decades old legacy code and there are lots of hard-coded credentials (not only in the code, but also in comments) for various servers and databases.

I do not want to make my team change all this code to store credentials in config files, I am not 100% sure our various tech stacks support this. It would also be very time consuming, and there is no guarantee we can find every single reference of credentials. I’m just wondering if it is safe to push the code with all these credentials even if the repositories we create are not public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing your code on GitHub is no less secure than storing it anywhere else.  For example, GitHub generally takes significant effort to secure repositories, and staff are not permitted to look at the contents of private repositories without the consent of the repository owner.  Pushing this code to GitHub will not intrinsically expose it any more than storing it on any other server.

However, having said that, storing credentials in your repository is a security problem regardless of where you host that code.  It is easy for a repository to accidentally leak for many reasons, due to server misconfiguration, laptop theft, or various other situations.  You would be well served to put at least a modicum of effort into using a more secure practice for storing credentials, if for no other reason than that you will have them stored in a single, secure place where you can find them all.  For example, rotating credentials is much easier when they all live in a tool like Vault and you can easily rotate a compromised credential across all systems.

So, in general, what you are doing is not very secure, but using or not using GitHub will not change that.

Comment: Thanks @bk2204. So with our codebase, using GitHub is no more/no less secure than if we were to set up a server as a remote within our own network and managed by our own organization, and then push our code to this remote? Which method would you recommend in our case?

Comment: Some companies want to have source code never leave their network and so they set up their own server, and some prefer the ease of use of a cloud-based solution.  In this case, both are going to be fine; GitHub offers on-premises options (GitHub Enterprise Server) if you like the features of GitHub but don't want to use a cloud option, and you can use other options as well.  It's really up to you what you want to do, since the same security concerns apply in both cases.

Comment: I'm very suspicious about this. Can't Microsoft search for some vital code within private repositories ? Ethically it shouldn't be, but technically it looks possible. We also hear leak news from social platforms quite often. I moved from Github to company `Gitea`.

Comment: It is of course technically possible but the terms of service don't permit it and employees are not allowed to access the contents without permission.  GitHub would be subject to massive liability if they did that.  This is no different from any other website where you store information, and GitHub has substantially stricter policies than most.  Of course, you are free to use a different solution if you think this is a concern and would like to host it yourself.  It really depends on your level of comfort.